# Substituting select option in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to substitute, the drop down options "Yes/No" to true and false so that I can make usage of ng-hide to make the appearance of an input field dynamic. But the binding is not working as desired.  Please check the JS bin link https://jsbin.com/piteqoduba/1/edit?html,output and advise.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>Delivery to same address?</p>
<ng-int="selectedVal={range.value}"></ng-int>
<select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="range.display for range  in range" >

</select>
<p  ng-hide= "selectedVal" >Fill your address below.</p>
<input type="text" ng-hide = "selectedVal">
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.range = [{display: "yes", value:true},
       {display: "no", value: false}
       ];
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Substitute

```
ng-options="range.display for range  in range"
```

with

```
ng-options="range.value as range.display for range  in range"
```

This will display **Yes/No** in **dropdown** while the values will be **true**/**false**.

Answer (score 1):

You will get an object in model so you have to do something like

```
<input type="text" ng-hide = "selectedVal.value">
```

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5oe1bm8f/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Actually you are using selected object for ng-hide="selectedVal". selectedVal is Object. That's a problem. You want true or false. So ng-hide="selectedVal.value" is correct.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>Delivery to same address?</p>
<ng-int="selectedVal={range.value}"></ng-int>
<select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="range.display for range in range" >

</select><p>{{selectedVal}}</p>
<p ng-hide="selectedVal.value" >Fill your address below.</p>
<input type="text" ng-hide="selectedVal.value">
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.range = [{display: "yes", value:true},
       {display: "no", value: false}
       ];
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what the diffrence between your answer and other answers?

Comment: Difference is explanation. And I added Snipt here with his example.